# Spring Integration response not populating json payload

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am trying to configure a simple http-inbound gateway which will accept a GET request and send some response as payload in JSON .
The Spring integration congiguration is below

```
<int:channel id="employeeSearchRequest" />
<int:channel id="employeeSearchResponse" />


<int-http:inbound-gateway id="inboundEmployeeSearchRequestGateway"
    supported-methods="GET, POST"
    request-channel="employeeSearchRequest"
    reply-channel="employeeSearchResponse"
    mapped-response-headers="Return-Status, Return-Status-Msg, HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS"
    view-name="/employee"
    path="/services/employee/{id}/search"
    reply-timeout="50000">

    <int-http:header name="employeeId" expression="#pathVariables.id"/>

</int-http:inbound-gateway>




<int:service-activator id="employeeServiceActivator"
                input-channel="employeeSearchRequest"
                output-channel="employeeSearchResponse"
                ref="employeeSearchService"
                method="getEmployee"
                requires-reply="true"
                send-timeout="60000"/>
```

The Employee search service is like :

```
@Service("employeeSearchService")
public class EmployeeSearchService {

private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(EmployeeSearchService.class);
/**
 * The API <code>getEmployee()</code> looks up the mapped in coming message header's id param
 * and fills the return object with the appropriate employee details. The return
 * object is wrapped in Spring Integration Message with response headers filled in.
 * This example shows the usage of URL path variables and how the service act on
 * those variables.
 * @param inMessage
 * @return an instance of <code>{@link Message}</code> that wraps <code>{@link EmployeeList}</code>
 */

public Message<PersonInfo> getEmployee(Message<?> inMessage){


    Map<String, Object> responseHeaderMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    MessageHeaders headers = inMessage.getHeaders();
    String id = (String)headers.get("employeeId");
    System.out.println("Oreeeeee " + id);
    PersonInfo info=new PersonInfo();
    info.setId(id);
    setReturnStatusAndMessage(responseHeaderMap);
    Message<PersonInfo> message = new GenericMessage<PersonInfo>(info, responseHeaderMap);
    return message;
}

/**
 * The API <code>setReturnStatusAndMessage()</code> sets the return status and return message
 * in the return message payload and its header.
 * @param status
 * @param message
 * @param employeeList
 * @param responseHeaderMap
 */
private void setReturnStatusAndMessage(
                    Map<String, Object> responseHeaderMap){


    responseHeaderMap.put("Return-Status", "Good");
    responseHeaderMap.put("Return-Status-Msg", "Maal peyechi");
}

}
```

When i am hitting the endpoint from postman the headers are getting populated but the payload is not coming as expected,it is coming as  :

```
{
"timestamp": 1581752821403,
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "No message available",
"path": "/services/employee/12/search"
}
```

I have com.fasterxml.jackson.core in classpath.

Any pointers what i am missing

Comment: There has to be some exception on the server. You also can turn on debug logging on the server to see what is going on when it receives a request

Comment: Any chances to understand how do you configure a Web app? How that Integration config is initialized and populated into an application context?